# How to populate user-defined type array from worksheet data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array of a user-defined type and want to get data from a worksheet into this array.  I have a solution but it seems inelegant.  Is there a better or easier way to do this?

```
Type Donation
    NBID As Integer
    Amount As Single
    DonationDate As Date
    TrackingCode As String
End Type

Public dons() as Donation

Sub init()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tmpDons() As Variant
    Dim donRows as Integer

    tmpDons = Sheets("Appeal Dons").UsedRange.Value2
    donRows = UBound(tmpDons)
    ReDim dons(donRows - 2)

    For i = 2 To donRows
        dons(i - 2).NBID = tmpDons(i, 1)
        dons(i - 2).Amount = tmpDons(i, 2)
        dons(i - 2).TrackingCode = tmpDons(i, 3)
        dons(i - 2).DonationDate = tmpDons(i, 4)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Public dons() As Donation`. You need to declare dons as an Array in order to use `ReDim`.

Comment: Thanks - this is just a typo in my question I have the parentheses in my code.  My code is working, I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Import to array the used range
        arr = .UsedRange

        'Loop from L to U arr bound
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            'Code
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```